# Contar solicitudes con Fechas de un año en especifico BASE_DATOS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

TRABAJO CON MICROSOFT SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT 2018[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes grupo quiero orientarme por parte de las personas que tienen mas conocimiento sobre el tema.

Lo que pasa ando haciendo un query que me cuente solicitudes por años,
Ejemplo tengo solicitudes de 2018 solo quiero que me cuente del `01/01/18` al `31/12/18` pero no se como hacerlo  tengo esto de query, pero quiero  que empieze del `01/01/18` al `31/12/18`  no desde la fecha actual.
Mi query

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha_registrada) AS ANOS, 
COUNT(no_solicitud) AS SOLICITUDES
 --fecha_registrada
FROM LIT_SRCartera
 where 
 fecha_registrada >=DATEADD(MONTH,-5, GETDATE()) 
 and fecha_registrada <=DATEADD(month,9, GETDATE()) 
and fecha_registrada is not null
GROUP BY  fecha_registrada
```

Quiero obtener el siguiente resultado

```
--------------------
|AÑO |  SOLICITUDES|
--------------------
|2018|    15       |
```

Pero que inicie del 01/01/18 al 31/12/18 nada más

Ayuda por favor

---

Disculpa me falto un pequeño detalle esto lo voy a traducir a una grafica y van a consultar,se que puedo poner 01/01/18 al 31/12/18 pero  a futuro van a consultar  y siempre va arrojar lo del 2018 QUIERO QUE  EN CUALQUIER MOMENTO ME ARROJE UN AÑO ANTES AL AÑO ACTUAL NO SE SI ME EXPLICO

Comment: simplemente usa `WHERE fecha_registrada >= '20180101' AND fecha_registrada < '20190101'`. Ah, y el group by está malo, debe ser `GROUP BY YEAR(fecha_registrada)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que te dieron la respuesta en un comentario, quiero llevarlo un poco más allá puesto que creo que quieres algo que no tengas que estar modificando.

Para calcular el inicio del año, utilizamos una técnica que consiste tomar los años de diferencia entre una fecha determinada y la fecha actual para después sumarlos a esa fecha determinada. El código queda de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha_registrada) AS ANOS, 
    COUNT(no_solicitud) AS SOLICITUDES
FROM LIT_SRCartera
WHERE fecha_registrada >= DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, '1900', GETDATE()), '1900') 
AND   fecha_registrada <  DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, '1900', GETDATE()) + 1, '1900') 
--and fecha_registrada is not null --No es necesaria
GROUP BY  YEAR(fecha_registrada);
```

De hecho, podríamos deshacernos del GROUP BY.

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS ANOS, 
    COUNT(no_solicitud) AS SOLICITUDES
FROM LIT_SRCartera
WHERE fecha_registrada >= DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, '1900', GETDATE()), '1900') 
AND   fecha_registrada <  DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, '1900', GETDATE()) + 1, '1900');
```

Nota final: Fíjate que usé un rango parcial para omitir el límite superior.

Comment: muchas gracias  me sirvio la información, ya comprendi que estaba haciendo mal, GRACIAS TODOS POR RESPONDER, YA LO ENTENDI

Comment: @josecas es muy importante que aclares que respuesta te sirivio, y la aceptes!!! por favor, hace el [tour] para entender como funciona el sitio

Answer (score 1):

Puede utilizar después del la cláusula `where`

```
and  fecha_registrada between '1/1/2018' and '31/12/2018'
```

O bien

```
and  fecha_registrada >= '1/1/2018' and fecha_registrada <= 
'31/12/2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer las comparaciones solo con los años de las fechas de tu consulta

ejemplo:

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha_registrada) AS ANOS, 
COUNT(no_solicitud) AS SOLICITUDES
 --fecha_registrada
FROM LIT_SRCartera
 where 
 YEAR(fecha_registrada)=YEAR(GETDATE()) 

and fecha_registrada is not null
GROUP BY  fecha_registrada
```

para obtener el año anterior a tu fecha actual

```
where YEAR(fecha_registrada)=YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1, getdate()))
```

Comment: Eso evitará que se pueda utilizar un índice en la consulta y a la larga (o corta) terminará por causar problemas de rendimiento. Te sugiero que dejes de utilizar ese método y comiences a utilizar rangos.

Comment: Eso que  me dices estes en el año que estes va agarrar el año anterior?

Comment: si, YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1, getdate())) toma la el año anterior de la fecha actual